# Trying to make a dynamic array of int and strings? I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: c

I have a class assignment where I need to take a txt file and **display**, **add**, and **remove** keys (int) and values (strings).

I would like to use a dynamic array for each (my professor said I can get extra credit if I do). Currently, this is what I have, I read the txt file and I add them to the array.

1. I don't know if creating a string with enough memory for any word and then copying it to a smaller char for less memory is needed (`strcpy(savStr, userStr);`)
2. I am not sure if I am doing the dynamic array correctly or how to add more indexes
3. I dont know if I am adding the memory to the array correctly

```
int main(int argc, char **argc) {
    int userNumber; //to take in user key and key in file
    char userStr[1000]; //initial string to take value from user and string
    int strL = 1; //find string length of value to find correct memory need to allocate
    char savStr[strL]; //value with memory allocate for the size of the string
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("values.txt", "r");
    int *keyArry;
    keyArry = (int *)calloc(8, sizeof(int));
    char *valueArry;
    valueArry = (char *)calloc(8, sizeof(char));
    int curr = 0;
    
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d,%s", &userNumber, userStr) != EOF) {
        strL = strlen(userStr);
        savStr[strL];
        strcpy(savStr, userStr);
        printf("%d - %s \n", cuserNumber, savStr);
        keyArry[curr] = userNumber;
        strcpy(&valueArry[curr], &savStr);
        curr++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d - %s \n", keyArry[i], &valueArry[i]);
    }
```

this is the txt file

```
1,one
2,two
3,three
4,four
5,five
6,six
7,seven
```

this is the what is added to the array

```
1 - ottffsseven  
2 - ttffsseven  
3 - tffsseven  
4 - ffsseven  
5 - fsseven  
6 - sseven  
7 - seven
```

Comment: Problem is here: `fscanf(fp,"%d,%s", &userNumber ,userStr) != EOF`  1) Why compare to `EOF` and not 2? 2) Why does format have a `','`, yet text file lacks commas?

Comment: also, that should be `savStr[strL+1];` for the `NUL` terminator. `strlen` does not include the `NUL` terminator in the length it returns (it also returns a `size_t` type).

Comment: What you have is not an array for 8 strings, but an array for 8 characters. Then you put `one` into the first 3 characters, then `two` into the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th positions (keeping an `o` at the first one), then `three` starting from the 3rd position (keeping a `t` in the 2nd one), and so on. So `ottffsseven` comes from the first letters of the previous strings. Of course that's longer than the 7 characters you could work with (+zero terminator), and it's also worth mentioning that `savStr` is even shorter, capable of storing a single zero terminator for a string.

Comment: I realized I didn't copy the text file over properly too the question, I am sorry for that. I corrected it in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior because `char savStr[strL];` defines an array of `char` with a length of `1`, just enough for the empty string.  Copying anything larger to it causes undefined behavior. Use `char savStr[1000];` instead.  After reading the rest of the code it seems this extra array is not needed at all.

Also note that `char *valueArry;` defines a pointer to `char`, which you initialize to point to an array of 8 `char`.  You should instead define a pointer to an array of `char *` and initialize it properly.

You professor wants you to use dynamic arrays, so you may need to reallocate them if the number of elements to store exceeds the allocated length.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argc) {
    int userNumber;     //to take in user key and key in file
    char userStr[1000]; //initial string to take value from user and string
    FILE *fp = fopen("values.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file values.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    int size = 8;
    int curr = 0;
    int *keyArry = calloc(size, sizeof(*keyArray));
    char **valueArry = calloc(size, sizeof(*valueArry));
    if (keyArry == NULL || valueArry == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate arrays\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d,%999s", &userNumber, userStr) == 2) {
        if (curr >= size) {
            // must reallocate the arrays
            size += size;
            keyArry = realloc(keyArry, size * sizeof(*keyArry);
            valueArry = realloc(valueArry, size * sizeof(*valueArry);
            if (keyArry == NULL || valueArry == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "cannot reallocate arrays\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        printf("%d - %s\n", cuserNumber, userStr);
        keyArry[curr] = userNumber;
        valueArry[curr] = strdup(userStr);
        curr++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < curr; i++) {
        printf("%d - %s \n", keyArry[i], &valueArry[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```